# Bind data to grid by using GET in WCF method data is not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

By using WCF post method, I stored data in database, then I want stored data display in grid control by using WCF GET. Here I wrote code to store data in database using POST method. It is working. I get error while binding stored data to grid control.

The below error I get:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.IService2' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

//service.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract()]
    void AddStudent(StudentDetails sd);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    Employee GetEmployee();
}
```

//service.svc

```
public class Service1 : IService1, IService2
{

    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "ADDStudent", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void AddStudent(StudentDetails sd)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mine"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into students values (@Studentname,@SDepartment,@SAddress,@SMobile)", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Studentname", sd.StudentName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDepartment", sd.SDepartment);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SAddress", sd.SAddress);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SMobile", sd.SMobile);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Empdetails", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Employee GetEmployee()
    {

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mine"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        //write code to bind data to a grid con5trol.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from students", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable st = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(st);
        emp.EmployeeTable = st;
        return emp;


    }

}

[DataContract()]
public class StudentDetails
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string SDepartment { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string SAddress { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string SMobile { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public DataTable EmployeeTable {  get; set;  }
}
```

//web.config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
          <add name="mine" connectionString="Data Source=
          (localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=yash;Integrated Security=true"/>
          </connectionStrings>
        <appSettings>
       <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" 
           />       
         </appSettings>
                  <system.web>
                 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
              <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
           </system.web>
              <system.serviceModel>

          <services> <!--1-->
               <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" 
                 name="CreateService.Service1">

                   <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Service1"  address="" 
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" 
          contract="CreateService.IService1">
       </endpoint>

        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Service1"  address=""
     binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" 
    contract="CreateService.IService2">
     </endpoint>




  </service>
</services>

           <behaviors> <!--2-->
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Service1">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
          </behaviors>

       <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
       <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
       </system.webServer>

        </configuration>
```

//////////////wcf consumption////////

```
using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
         using System.Linq;
          using System.Web;
            using System.Web.UI;
              using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
                using System.ServiceModel;
           using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
            using System.Runtime.Serialization;
          using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
      using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
           using System.IO;
          using System.Net;
   using System.Data;
        using System.Data.SqlClient;
        using System.Text;
           using ConsumptionWcf.ServiceReference1;
        namespace ConsumptionWcf
           {
         public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
            {
    public class StudentDetails
              {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string SDepartment { get; set; }
        public string SAddress { get; set; }
        public string SMobile { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Service1Employee semp = new Service1Employee();
        Service2Client myservice = new Service2Client();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp = myservice.GetEmployee();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = emp.EmployeeTable;
        grid1.DataSource = dt;
        grid1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StudentDetails stu = new StudentDetails
        {
           // StudentName = TextBox1.Text,
            //  StudentName = Request["TextBox1"],
            //StudentName = Request.Params["TextBox1"],
            StudentName = Request.Form["TextBox1"],//Request Is Propery Of 
    Request Collections,Request Collection Object Is HttpRequest. 
             //Above Four Are The Methods To Collect Data At The Server 
         Side.

            //SAddress = TextBox2.Text,
            //SAddress = Request["TextBox2"],
            //SAddress =  Request.Params["TextBox2"],
            SAddress = Request.Form["TextBox2"],

            //SMobile = TextBox3.Text,
            //SMobile = Request["TextBox3"],
            //SMobile = Request.Params["TextBox3"],
            SMobile = Request.Form["TextBox3"],

            //SDepartment = TextBox4.Text
            //    SDepartment = Request["TextBox4"]
             //SDepartment = Request.Params["TextBox4"]
            SDepartment = Request.Form["TextBox4"]

        };
        DataContractJsonSerializer objseria = new 
                DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(StudentDetails));
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        objseria.WriteObject(mem, stu);
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, 
    (int)mem.Length);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;


  webClient.UploadString("http://localhost:58369/Service1.svc/ADDStudent", 
              "POST", data);

        Label1.Text = "Details saved using Rest service";
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");



        DataContractJsonSerializer objseria1 = new 
        DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(StudentDetails));
        MemoryStream mem1 = new MemoryStream();
        objseria.WriteObject(mem, stu);
        string data1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, 
         (int)mem.Length);
        WebClient webClient1 = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    webClient.UploadString("http://localhost:58369/Service1.svc/Empdetails", 
    "GET", data);

    }
       }
```

Comment: Please, do not post your entire programs here. Isolate code that doesn't work. This questions, the way it is posted, falls under "why this code is not working". And don't expect that someone will code and post code in the placeholder you left there

Answer (score 0):

As I see your service.cs is the namespace for below code

```
     namespace service
   {
        public class Service1 : IService1, IService2
        {

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "ADDStudent", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public void AddStudent(StudentDetails sd)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mine"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
           //rest of the code
        }
}
```

But your web.config file which describes the configuration has different name and hence endpoint not defined exception is thrown,the name of the service must be the namespace followed by the class that is implementing the service contract types .Below is the modified code.

//web.config file

```
     <services> <!--1 name =Namespace.ImplementingClass-->
                           <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" 
                             name="service.Service1">

         <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Service1"  address="" 
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" 
              contract="CreateService.IService1">
           </endpoint>
```

Comment: Thank You,Here you wrote code for one end point,how to write configurations for another end point.

Comment: @lavangoud ,you can add as many endpoints you want in your web.config file,I have just taken one endpoint to write minimal code.